# Repositories some help

Tags: package-management, repository

I want to install on ubuntu 14.04 framework cppcms so I have commands from official website http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/apt

Commands are:

> ```
> deb http://apt.cppcms.com/ utopic main  
> deb-src http://apt.cppcms.com/ utopic main
>
> apt-get source cppcms  
> apt-get build-dep cppcms  
> cd cppcms-X.Y.Z  
> dpkg-buildpackage
> ```

When I do deb http://apt.cppcms.com/ utopic main, nothing works, have someone any idea why?

Comment: These are not commands at all. First two lines should be added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: how ca I add to that list? some commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines are not commands. The best way is to create a list file for this repository. You can do it this way

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cppcms.list <<< "deb http://apt.cppcms.com/ trusty main"
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cppcms.list <<< "deb-src http://apt.cppcms.com/ trusty main"
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you can run the rest of commands, that are really commands.

But it seems that you do not have to build it from source. You can install the binary by

```
sudo apt-get install cppcms-tools libcppcms-dev
```

Comment: What is this? WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!   cppcms
E: Some packages could not be authenticated

Comment: That's OK. There is no authentication.

Comment: And why do you try to build packages, if there already deb binaries there?

Comment: where is binaries? and how I will authenticate?

Comment: I updated my answer about the binary. And you do not need to authenticate.

Comment: says E: Unable to locate package cppcms

Comment: Sry, updated my question. Another command.

Comment: It will not install for 14.04. I updated first commands too. Do from the beginning.

Comment: Great, Now works perfectly.